# Java Recursive Decompression Program Doesn't Finish

Tags: java, recursion, standard-library, compression

I am trying to make a program to decompress a string that was compressed using RLE. The decompression program, however, must be written recursively, without loops, and without declaring variables outside the method. Below is my closest attempt so far, I am able to get the first "piece" of the compressed string (ex: 4w, q, g, J, 6y, etc.) decompressed. It just won't print out anything else after that, and I'm having trouble understanding why. much thanks

```
public class StringRec{

public static void main(String[] a){
System.out.println("string: ");
String decomp = IO.readString();
System.out.println(decompress(decomp));
}

public static String decompress(String compressedText){
    int count = compressedText.length();
    String index = "";

 if(count == 0){
        return "";  
}
```

I though to make a few conditions that don't call the decompress method again, 
because the condition for them is that they are the last piece in the string, so after their part is decompressed its done. Naturally, there calling would occur at the end of the runtime, after the other conditions with the decompress call have been called. Not sure why it isn't working.

```
else{
 if(Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0))){

        String s = String.format("%0" + compressedText.charAt(0) + "d", 0).replace('0', compressedText.charAt(1));
        index = s;
        compressedText = compressedText.substring(2);
        decompress(compressedText);

    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0)) && compressedText.length()==2){ 

        String s2 = String.format("%0" + compressedText.charAt(0) + "d", 0).replace('0', compressedText.charAt(1));
        index = s2;

    }else if(Character.isLetter(compressedText.charAt(0))){     

        String s3 = Character.toString(compressedText.charAt(0));
        index = s3;
        compressedText = compressedText.substring(1);
        decompress(compressedText);

    }
    else if(Character.isLetter(compressedText.charAt(0)) && compressedText.length()==1){

        String s4 = Character.toString(compressedText.charAt(0));
        index = s4;

    }
return index;
}
}
```

My current guesses are that it has something to do with how the decompress method is called, or its a problem with how I arrange the output to be returned after the decompress method is already called, but then I wouldn't be able to explain how the first part of the string works consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static String decompress(String compressedText) {
    int count = compressedText.length();
    if (count == 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0))) {
        String s = String.format("%0" + compressedText.charAt(0) + "d", 0)
                .replace('0', compressedText.charAt(1));
        return s + decompress(compressedText.substring(2));
    } else if (Character.isLetter(compressedText.charAt(0))) {
        String s3 = Character.toString(compressedText.charAt(0));
        return s3 + decompress(compressedText.substring(1));
    } else
        return compressedText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works, and I think I understand why, but: on the return statements, is it important that it returns the string, plus activating the decompress again, or could that portion work if decompress came first, and then plus the string

Comment: If you write ```return decompress(...) + s;``` and ```return decompress(...) + s3```, you will get reversed result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you forgot to 'concatenate' the result of the recursive decompress calls with the current index variable value. Because of this you 'drop' the results of the recursive calls and only have the result of the first call.

If you modify the `decompress(compressedText)` lines with `index = index + decompress(compressedText)` in your code, your results will be what you would expect.

(Btw, you should rename the topic to something like '*Java Recursive Decompression Program does not get the expected result*' because from the title I would expect some code which produces infinite recursive calls :) )